# NSCameraUsageDescription doesn't work on Expo Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, permissions, camera, expo

I want to change my APP'S camera permission message tho, I couldn't do it. 
I added the infoPlist on the app.json like the below photo.

[image]

Do you know why it doesn't work?
Now, apple rejected my app because the camera permission message is too obscure.

[Expo info]
sdkVersion: 36.0.0
version: 1.0.3

Comment: Same i am facing the same issue.. is there anyone who know how to fix this..

Answer (score 2):

Execute `expo prebuild` to modify the `./ios` and `./android` files to reflect the changes you make to your `app.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem. Although It didn't reflect on Expo, After cleaning and rebuilding, it works.

The clean command is below.

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -f package-lock.json && rm -f yarn.lock && npm cache verify && npm install
```

Comment: SDK 39 and didn't work for me. I also deleted expo client, rebuild for ios review (rejected for sure), changed simulator. I dont know if there is something missing.

Comment: This didn't work for me either